# Display age from birth date with ACF

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I try to set up the automatic display of a person’s age, same way as Wikipedia does, using ACF date field.

exemple (in french) : 17 mai 1990 (33 ans)

here is my code:

```
<?php echo get_field( 'person-birthday', $post->ID ); ?> //display the date in 'j F Y' format.
<?php $date_string = get_field( 'person-birthday', $post->ID );  $date = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'Ymd', $date_string );  $birthday = new DateTime( $date );  $interval = $birthday->diff( new DateTime );  echo '(' .$interval->y.' ans)'; ?>
```

My issue is that the age always display “0”. Is there something wrong in my code ?

Comment: If your date is stored in j F Y format, you would need to match this in your call to createFromFormat (you currently have Ymd).

Answer (score 0):

The issue with the code provided is that the **$birthday** variable is being set to a new **DateTime** object with the **$date** variable passed as a parameter, which is unnecessary since **$date** is already a **DateTime** object. Additionally, the **$interval** variable is being set to the difference between **$birthday** and a new **DateTime** object, which is not correct since **$birthday** is already a **DateTime** object representing the person's birthday.

To fix the issue, the code should be modified as follows:

```
<?php 
$date_string = get_field( 'person-birthday', $post->ID );  
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'Ymd', $date_string );  
$interval = $date->diff( new DateTime );  
echo '(' .$interval->y.' ans)'; 
?>
```

This code should correctly calculate the person's age based on their birthday stored in the ACF date field. If the issue persists, it may be worth checking that the date format in the ACF field matches the format specified in the createFromFormat function.